# Mention in comments rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, comments, asset-pipeline, mention

I have a comments module in my rails app I want to add mention system in comments like facebook I want to show full name in comment with '@' I'm using mention.js but the problem is I can show username in comments and then notify users after finding them by username. But I want to show full name in comment where full name is not unique is there any gem which provide this functionality. I want to send ajax request like typeahead to find matching users to show suggestions.

Comment: How did you manage backend for the above functionality?